# Processing a handle to a module

Tags: assembly

I have found the following lines in a sample which I try to analyze. Here, are the lines:

```
   ....
   push  afg.00401189       "ntdll.dll" 
   call  GetmoduleHandleW
   neg   eax
   sbb   eax, eax
   neg   eax
   RETN
```

So, I do not understand the lines after the call instruction. We have sbb instruction between two neg-operations, but what can be the purpose of that. Can somebody explain that ?

PS: Intuitively, I would say that at the end I have the handle to ntdll.dll in EAX...but the operations between the call and retn are very strange. I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `neg / sbb / neg` code in your question is the equivalent of the following C code:

```
eax = (eax != 0)
```

In other words, the function returns `GetModuleHandleW("ntdll.dll") != NULL`.

The `neg / sbb / neg` construct is explained in detail here:

[*Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering*, section A.2.8.1. Pure Arithmetic Implementations](https://books.google.com/books?id=_78HnPPRU_oC&pg=PT392)